# How to setup RStudio Server authentication for CentOS 7

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I installed [RStudio Server (Open)](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio-server-pro/) on a CentOS 6.3 server following the basic instructions, and was able to authenticate using my system user and password without any problems.

However, when I tried the same (even same version of RStudio Server) on a CentOS 7.2 server, I'm unable to authenticate. It just tells me that the username and password aren't recognized. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deep in the [useful and exhaustive documentation](http://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/authenticating-users.html#default-pam-configuration), I found the answer!

> On RedHat, CentOS and SUSE systems applications without their own PAM profiles are denied access by default. Therefore to ensure that RStudio is running and available after installation a default PAM profile is installed at /etc/pam.d/rstudio

The default PAM profile doesn't work on CentOS7 though it appears to have on CentOS6.3. To fix this, follow their suggested steps of copying a working PAM profile over to the RStudio one:

```
sudo cp /etc/pam.d/login /etc/pam.d/rstudio
```

Hope this helps someone else who stumbles here!